# How to build a native-image Docker image that runs multiple architectures?

Tags: docker, arm64, micronaut, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I would like to create a multi architecture Docker image containing the native-image binary of my Micronaut application.

When running `./gradlew dockerfileNative` Micronaut generates a `Dockerfile` using a multi-staged build to create the native image of the Micronaut application. Usually the `Dockerfile` looks like this

```
FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image:ol7-java17-22.2.0 AS graalvm
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY layers/libs /home/app/libs
COPY layers/classes /home/app/classes
COPY layers/resources /home/app/resources
COPY layers/application.jar /home/app/application.jar
RUN mkdir /home/app/config-dirs
COPY config-dirs/generateResourcesConfigFile /home/app/config-dirs/generateResourcesConfigFile
RUN native-image -cp /home/app/libs/*.jar:/home/app/resources:/home/app/application.jar --no-fallback -H:Name=application -J--add-exports=org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.configure=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jni=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.nativeimage.impl=ALL-UNNAMED -H:ConfigurationFileDirectories=/home/app/config-dirs/generateResourcesConfigFile -H:Class=ch.onstructive.salessystem.Application
FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc:alpine-3.12
RUN apk --no-cache update && apk add libstdc++
EXPOSE 8080
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl -s localhost:8080/endpoints/health | grep '"status":"UP"'
COPY --from=graalvm /home/app/application /app/application
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/application"]
```

Micronaut uses `ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image:ol7-java17-22.2.0` as the base image for the multi-stage build. Inspecting the base image on my MacBook M1, I see that the base image supports the `arm64` architecture.

```bash
❯ docker image inspect --format "{{.RepoTags}} {{.Architecture}}" ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image:ol7-java17-22.2.0
[ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image:ol7-java17-22.2.0] arm64
```

In the second stage Micronaut uses `frolvlad/alpine-glibc:alpine-3.12` and copies the native-image binary into it. The problem with this Docker image is, that it only supports `amd64` and therefore cannot run on Mac M1 or other `arm64` based systems.

```bash
❯ docker image inspect --format "{{.RepoTags}} {{.Architecture}}" frolvlad/alpine-glibc:alpine-3.12             
[frolvlad/alpine-glibc:alpine-3.12] amd64
```

Is there an alternative Docker image out there, that supports both `arm64` (aka `aarch64`) and `amd64`?

Comment: "Is there an alternative Docker image out there, that supports both arm64 (aka aarch64) and amd64?" - There are many of them.  Do you have requirements aside from needing to run a Micronaut native image inside the container?

Comment: The only additional requirement is to have e.g. curl installed to register a healthceck

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over a Docker image in the Micronaut Gradle Plugin [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-gradle-plugin/latest/#native-image)

```
tasks.named('dockerfileNative') {
    baseImage('gcr.io/distroless/cc-debian10')
}
```

This image works for both `arm64` and `amd64`.
And if you need e.g. `curl` to implement a health check you can use

```
tasks.named("dockerfileNative") {
    baseImage('ubuntu:22.04')
    instruction """RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*"""
    instruction """HEALTHCHECK CMD curl -s localhost:8080/endpoints/health | grep '"status":"UP"'"""
}
```